# c++ FindFirstFile Cannot convert const char to basic_string

Tags: c++

`FindFirstFile` function somehow doesn't accept my wstring (nor string) to be passed as a parameter.

I get a compiler error

```
Cannot convert const char[9] to std::basic_string
```

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>


using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wstring path = "C:\\*.dmp";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA dataFile;
    HANDLE hFind;

    hFind = FindFirstFile (path.c_str(), &dataFile);


    cout << "The name of the first found file is %s \n" dataFile.cFileName << endl;
    FindClose hFind;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a compiler error
>
> ```
> Cannot convert const char[9] to std::basic_string
> ```

You need a [wide char literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) to initialize a `std::wstring` properly:

```
wstring path = L"C:\\*.dmp";
            // ^
```

---

Also you have missed to put another `<<`

```
cout << "The name of the first found file is " << dataFile.cFileName << endl;`
                                            // ^^
```

Also note that [output formatting with `std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is different from `printf()` format string styles. Note I removed the `%s` from the above sample.

Comment: @Muteking It was another one I've answered first, take a look again.

Comment: Almost perfect Panta rei, but now this error creeps in: syntax error ';' missing before hFind indentifier.(After endl)

Comment: @Muteking You probably missed to include something else, where's `FindClose` coming from? Anyway that's unrelated to your original question. Another error, another question please. I'm not here to feed help vampires.

Comment: I was just missing a parenthesis FindClose(hFind)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const char path[] = "C:\\*.dmp";           // C-style string

hFind = FindFirstFile(path, &dataFile);    // Pass the string directly
```